# System.IO.FileLoadException

Tags: .net, asp.net, assemblies

Getting "System.IO.FileLoadException: Unable to load file or assembly" when trying to bind localized resources assembly from the separate project.

> Fusion Log shows: ERR: Setup failed
>   with hr = 0x80070005. ERR: Failed to
>   complete setup of assembly (hr =
>   0x80070005). Probing terminated.

Trying to solve this for 3 hours already, nothing helps.

Comment: Maybe you could show us all the fusionlog details? And does the FileLoadException also have an InternalException?

Comment: You have been trying for 3 hours, but you are not stating what you have tried, what went wrong, etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found out that there was lack of privileges for impersonated user. Sorry for that question, but maybe it could help somebody else.

Comment: Don't be sorry for asking a question :) Good that you found the solution yourself though!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with following error message
"Could not load file or assembly 'TestGUI, Version=x.x.x.xxxxxxx, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)"

How do I check the file dependency. Used Dependency walker and copied all the files missing into System32 still not able to resolve this issue.